# get the value of item select while it is in a foreach loop in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to retrieve the value of selected item while it is inside a loop 
to print it in javascript (`alert(value)`). I can't do this `document.getelementbyid` because it is inside a loop and the id will be repeated many times.

```
<?PHP
    foreach ($res->fetchAll() as $row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
        <input type="text" hidden value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " id="idartwork">
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>                                     
    </td>

    <td>                
        <?php echo $row['creation_date']; ?>                            
    </td>

    <td>                
        <?php echo $row['artist']; ?>                                   
    </td>

    <td>
<?php
    if ($row['gallery'] == "") {
?>
    <select id="selectname">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="ghaya gallery">ghaya gallery</option>
        <option value="selma gallery">selma gallery</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="affecter" onclick="affecter()">
    <input type="text" hidden value="<?php echo $row['gallery']; ?> " id="inputgallery">
    <!-- <input type="text" hidden value="--><?php //echo $row['id']; ?><!-- " id="idartwork">-->

<?php
} else {
echo $row['gallery'];
?>

<?php
}
?>
</td>
```

what I want to do is take the value of item select and put it in affecter() so I could print it

[image]

Comment: post code and not an image of it and all related/relevant code.

Comment: share your code here and remove id from element and try with class

Comment: sorry for this, I have edited my post now it contains the code

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly so my answer was not correct. I have re edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `$i` variable with your foreach loop. Then add that `$i` to the end of each ID name, then increase the `$i` at the end of each loop. That way, when the loop creates the next element, each one will have a unique ID. Then you can use `getElementByID` in JavaScript.

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($res->fetchAll() as $row) { ?>
     ...
    <select id="selectname<?php echo $i; ?>">
    ...
    <input type="button" value="affecter" onclick="affecter(<?php echo $i; ?>)">
    <?php $i++;
}  ?>
```

Now your selects will have a unique ID of `selectname0`, `selectname1`, etc.
And your JavaScript `onclick` function will know the `$i` number of that element.

Then your JavaScript function becomes: `function affecter(i)`
and add `i` to your `getElementByID("selectname"+i)`

Comment: I thought about that but how will I know what is the id ? it could be test1 or test2 etc ?

Comment: I cant access $i inside javascript

Comment: You can also add a parameter to the affector( ) function with each loop. That's how you pass the `$i` to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

Duplicate ID are bad, use class instead. But that's not the point of this answer.

**Steps to get selected value:**

change the html to get the context (learn more about [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes)).

```
onclick="affecter(this)"
```

get [parent node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) of that input box,

```
const parentNode = element.parentNode;
```

[get the select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex),

```
const e = parentNode.querySelector("#selectname");
const selectedName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
// const selectedName = e.value; // some prefers this way
```

Use it.

```
alert(selectedName);
```

```js
function affecter(element) {
  const parentNode = element.parentNode;
  const e = parentNode.querySelector("#selectname");
  const selectedName = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  parentNode.querySelector("b span").innerHTML = selectedName;
}
```

```css
tr td {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="selectname">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="ghaya gallery">ghaya gallery</option>
            <option value="selma gallery" selected>selma gallery</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="affecter" onclick="affecter(this)">
        <b>selected: <span></span></span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="selectname">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="ghaya gallery">ghaya gallery</option>
          <option value="selma gallery" selected>selma gallery</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="affecter" onclick="affecter(this)">
        <b>selected: <span></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I m sorry but when I tried to do it multiple times it doesn't do anything console says TypeError: element is undefined   it worked one but not more than that

Comment: I cannot say much since I don't see that error here. You have to update your question with more screenshots and solutions.

Comment: It was probably something I did wrong but I'm curious I just want to understand why you put affecter(this) what does "this" actually represents ? if you could clarify this for or just a website that you think it will be useful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this represents the context of that page element. You should learn more about this and scopes. Search for "ydkjs this & object prototypes"

Answer (score 0):

Add a `unique` identifier to the `id` of each of your `select` objects. This could be done even easier by just applying a `.on('click'` listener directly to the `select` element using `jQuery`, but here is the direct answer to your question:

```js
function affecter(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    var itemValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(itemValue);
}
```

```html
<?PHP
    foreach ($res->fetchAll() as $row) 
    {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
         <?php
             // The `id` field should be a proper identifier so we will use it
             echo $row['id'];
         ?>
        <input type="text" hidden value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?> " id="idartwork">
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>                                     
    </td>

    <td>                
        <?php echo $row['creation_date']; ?>                            
    </td>

    <td>                
        <?php echo $row['artist']; ?>                                   
    </td>

    <td>
<?php
    if ($row['gallery'] == "") 
    {
        // Add a unique identifier to the end of each id
        echo '<select id="selectname'.$row['id'].'">';
?>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="ghaya gallery">ghaya gallery</option>
        <option value="selma gallery">selma gallery</option>
    </select>

<?php
    // Send the id to the function affecter()
    echo '<input type="button" value="affecter" onclick="affecter(\'selectname'.$row['id'].'\')">
    <input type="text" hidden value="'.$row['gallery'].'" id="inputgallery">';
}
else
{
    echo $row['gallery'];
?>
```